# log4j not writing into file but its writing into console

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, log4j2

i am aritinga small application in Linux based system where i am using slf4j libraries for logger

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

i could see the logs are visible in console but not appending to log files.

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="threshold" value="INFO" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ABSOLUTE}][%-5p][%-10t]%m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>






<!-- EXAMPLE logging setup NOTES: 1. files are written to "./logs/<filename>". 
    You must setup the environment so that ./logs is a symlink to the correct 
    location according to the EXAMPLE log standard. For example, "/opt/logs/". 
    If that's not possible, change the File setting in each appender appropriately. -->

<appender name="EXAMPLE_AUDIT" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="threshold" value="INFO" />
    <param name="File" value="./logs/audit.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="128MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="20" />
    <layout class="com.rsg.ova.logging.log4j.EXAMPLELayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="EXAMPLE_AUDIT" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="EXAMPLE_METRIC" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    <param name="File" value="./logs/metric.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="128MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <layout class="com.rsg.ova.logging.log4j.EXAMPLELayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="EXAMPLE_METRIC" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="EXAMPLE_ERROR" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="threshold" value="ERROR" />    <!-- only WARN and ERROR are allowed in this log -->
    <param name="File" value="./logs/error.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="128MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <layout class="com.rsg.ova.logging.log4j.EXAMPLELayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="EXAMPLE_ERROR" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="EXAMPLE_DEBUG" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    <param name="File" value="./logs/debug.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="128MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="20" />
    <layout class="com.rsg.ova.logging.log4j.EXAMPLELayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="EXAMPLE_DEBUG" />
    </layout>
</appender>


<logger name="com.rsg.EXAMPLE.audit" additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_AUDIT" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.rsg.EXAMPLE.metrics" additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_METRIC" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.rsg.EXAMPLE.error" additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_ERROR" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.rsg.EXAMPLE.debug" additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_DEBUG" />
</logger>


<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />

</root>

<logger name="org.openEXAMPLE.agcp.commonFunction.input"
    additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.openEXAMPLE.agcp.commonFunction.output"
    additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />

</logger>

<logger name="org.openEXAMPLE.agcp.commonFunction.error"
    additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_ERROR" />
</logger>

<!-- The EXAMPLE logging standard has four specific classes of logging that 
    are unrelated to subsystem logger names. If you want them activated, uncomment 
    this block. -->
<logger name="com.rsg.EXAMPLE.audit" additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_AUDIT" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.rsg.EXAMPLE.metrics" additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_METRIC" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.rsg.EXAMPLE.error" additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_ERROR" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.rsg.EXAMPLE.debug" additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_DEBUG" />
</logger>


<logger name="com.rsg.ova.apiClient.http.HttpClient" additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.rsg.ova.roman.client.impl.romanSimplerBatchPublisher"
    additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has been identified that i have to include sl4j-log4j bridge jar to resolve above issue, i was including log4j and sl4j individual jars , due to this i can see no compilation errors but the bridge is not fulfilling.

after removing individual jars and adding bridge jar the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your logback.xml file configuration. It seems that the root tag("configuration") is missing. Can you add and check it?.

Refer https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Comment: Try one more thing , use log4j.properties instead of log4j.xml. I can provide you the properties file if you want.

Comment: we have to use log4j2.xml as per project requirements

Comment: Oh sorry. I thought that you are using logback. If you are using log4j2 means, then the configuration should be put into log4j2.xml file instead of log4j.xml.

Comment: sorry, i have to use log4j.xml,

Comment: Did you fix it or still having it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed root tag in your xml file. Please find the below code to write the logs in a file.

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="false" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="128MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="20" />
    <param name="file" value="./logs/audit.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
```

Comment: have added root tags as like below, but no luck <br>


<root>
                <level value="DEBUG" />
                <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_DEBUG" />
                <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_METRIC" />
                <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_AUDIT" />
                <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE_ERROR" />
                <appender-ref ref="FILE" />

        </root>

Answer (score 0):

The configuration shown in the question is in the log4j 1.2 format.

The format for `log4j2.xml` is different. It is plugin based so you don't need to specify the class name of the appenders any more.

Please see the Log4j2 [manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender). It has many examples configurations.